# Jenkins install plugin failfure

Tags: jenkins

Beacuse I cannot install it by connecting network, I just copied the file sonar.hpi/jpi to directory /jenkins_home/plugin/, and restart jenkins.
But it doesn't work, I didn't find the plugin appeared in installed tab.
Anyone knows it please tell me, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are missing some dependency. Jenkins will not show plugins which fail to load, due to dependency problems.

You should try installing the plugin through the web UI, I think that should install the prerequisites.

Alternatively, look at the log files ("find in files" of some editor helps here, or plain `grep`), and see what exception is thrown by that plugin. There is likely to be an exception telling some class can't be found. The missing class name should give pretty good idea about what plugin is missing. Install it, then try restarting Jenkins.

- According to https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Redmine+Plugin Redmine needs [subversion](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin) plugin (may be installed by default, not sure).
- According to https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sonar+plugin Sonar needs [javadoc](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Javadoc+Plugin) plugin and [maven](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin) plugin.

If this does not help, still try to find the relevant exception(s) in Jenkins log files, and add them to the question...

Comment: First of all, thanks for you replying. I just want to install two plugins, one is sonar, the other one is redmine. Actually, I don't know what's the dependency about it. Beacuse I cannot install it by connecting network, I just copy sonar.hpi and redmine.hpi to directory jenkins_home/plugin.

Comment: By dependency I mean, those plugins probably use services offered by some other plugin. So if that some other plugin is not installed, and Sonar or Redmine try to use them, it will not work.

Comment: @user2999262 The customary way to say "thank you" at Stack Overflow is to upvote the answer which was helpful ;). Also, for future, once the problem is solved, show that by accepting the best or most helpful answer (and if nobody wrote good answer and you solved it yourself, write and accept your own answer).